# No Wifi in Lubuntu installed Mac Mini

Tags: networking, wireless, lubuntu, mac

I have installed Lubuntu 18.04 on my Mac Mini but it cannot find the wifi.

I also tried to install Ubuntu 18.04 and it can find the wifi on my Mac Mini.

I understand that Lubuntu is light weight and does not come with the same set of features as Ubuntu. Does that mean I cannot expect to install Lubuntu on my Mac Mini and get wifi to work?

EDIT:
I now tried to re-install ubuntu 18.04 and I have the same problem - it cannot find wifi either - so its not related to Lubuntu it seems.

It might be that back when I installed 18.04 the first time I had wired internet so it managed to install the required driver.

Also as requested I tried to run:

```
$ lspci -nnk | grep 0280 -A3
02:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Broadcom Limited BCM4331 802.11a/b/g/n [14e4:4331] (rev 02)
    Subsystem: Apple Inc. AirPort Extreme [106b:010e]
    Kernel driver in use: wl
    Kernel modules: bcma, wl
```

Comment: Lubuntu at it's core contains the bulk of Ubuntu, but with a different DEsktop.  If you have Ubuntu, you can `sudo lshw -C network` to view your hardware info (network class hardware only) and see the "driver=" details needed to make your wifi work.  You can then compare it with Lubuntu, which I'd expect to be the same, but even if it isn't you know what you need to install/configure to get it working on Lubuntu too.  (*ps: if Ubuntu isn't installed anymore; you can view the info from install media and selecting 'try ubuntu' too*)

Comment: Ok but why do I need to install drivers manually on lubuntu - which I assume will require internet - when it just works out of the box on Ubuntu?

Comment: While booted into Lubuntu, please run: `lspci -nnk | grep 0280 -A3` and then edit your question to include the result.